# Download multiple files concurrently with control on each downloading task using Alamofire swift 2.1

Tags: concurrency, download, alamofire, swift2

Download multiple files concurently using Alamofire in swift 2.1 with stop , pause and delete options om each individual downloading file ....
I tried a lot but did not get any proper solution...
Please reply 
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chain multiple Alamofire requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634995/chain-multiple-alamofire-requests)

Comment: Thanks Tomasz.. but my question is different ,I want to download multiple file concurrently , and I could also pause,stop,delete every file individuly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021896/nsurlsession-concurrent-requests-with-alamofire

Comment: Now I able to download multiple url concurrently ... But problem in how to cancel, resume and stop individual url(task) please suggest me Tomasz..Thanks in advance..