# Alamofire number of requests one after another

Tags: swift, io, alamofire

I have a number of requests witch I would like to call one after another without having nested spaghetti code.

I tried it already with a serial dispatch queue

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("label", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseString { (response:Response<String, NSError>) in
            print(1)
        }

Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseString { (response:Response<String, NSError>) in
            print(2)
        }

Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseString { (response:Response<String, NSError>) in
            print(3)
        }
```

But unfortunately that does not work. The output of this can be 1,3,2 or 3,1,2 or any other combination.

What would be the best approach to get the output 1,2,3 so one after the other.

Comment: do you have n number of tries, or you already know how many request you will have?

Comment: I know how many Ill have but of course it would be better to be dynamic

Comment: Have you tried to use a `dispatch_semaphore` ? I don't have time actually to reply with a good answer, but you can find a lot of examples here in SO

Comment: Alamofire only supports `dispatch_queue_t` :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chain multiple Alamofire requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634995/chain-multiple-alamofire-requests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I ended up writing my own implementation.

I created a class `RequestChain` wich takes `Alamofire.Request` as parameter

```
class RequestChain {
    typealias CompletionHandler = (success:Bool, errorResult:ErrorResult?) -> Void

    struct ErrorResult {
        let request:Request?
        let error:ErrorType?
    }

    private var requests:[Request] = []

    init(requests:[Request]) {
        self.requests = requests
    }

    func start(completionHandler:CompletionHandler) {
        if let request = requests.first {
            request.response(completionHandler: { (_, _, _, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    completionHandler(success: false, errorResult: ErrorResult(request: request, error: error))
                    return
                }
                self.requests.removeFirst()
                self.start(completionHandler)
            })
            request.resume()
        }else {
            completionHandler(success: true, errorResult: nil)
            return
        }

    }
}
```

And I use it like this

```
let r1 = Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseArray(keyPath: "endpoints") { (response: Response<[CountryModel],NSError>) in
    print("1")
}

let r2 = Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseArray(keyPath: "endpoints") { (response: Response<[CountryModel],NSError>) in
    print("2")
}

let r3 = Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseArray(keyPath: "endpoints") { (response: Response<[CountryModel],NSError>) in
    print("3")
}

let chain = RequestChain(requests: [r1,r2,r3])

chain.start { (success, errorResult) in
    if success {
        print("all have been success")
    }else {
        print("failed with error \(errorResult?.error) for request \(errorResult?.request)")
    }


}
```

Importent is that you are telling the Manager to not execute the request immediately

```
    let manager = Manager.sharedInstance
    manager.startRequestsImmediately = false
```

Hope it will help someone else

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Artman's Signals](https://github.com/artman/Signals) to notify my app once a result is returned, after which a queue elsewhere can call it's next request:

```
Alamofire.request( httpMethod, url, parameters: params ).responseJSON
{
    ( response: Response< AnyObject, NSError > ) in

    self._signals.dispatchSignalFor( Key: url, data: response.result )
}
```

More details [here](http://josephbeuysmum.co.uk/on-signals-in-swift/).

Comment: Interesting approach! Thank for this hit but it will not fit in my code base. Thx

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to call your second request in the first one's callback :

```
Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseString { (response:Response<String, NSError>) in
            print(1)
            Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseString { (response:Response<String, NSError>) in
                 print(2)
                 Alamofire.request(Router.Countries).responseString { (response:Response<String, NSError>) in
                      print(3)
                 }
            }
        }
```