# Using Alamofire to upload multiple Images serially

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, alamofire, image-uploading

I am developing an app, and one the function is letting our user to submit comments for a product with photos. And when I developing the image upload part, I got stuck with the following issue:

If user selected more than 1 photos, How can I upload the images to sever through RESTful API serially. I don't want to let user upload image concurrently. If one of the photo upload failed, I don't want the following photo to continue uploading. That means, photo should upload one by one, and one of them failed, then uploading process will stop, and call the `completion` callback with `false`. If all uploaded, then call the `completion` with `true`.

So what should I do to accomplish this goal? Any suggestion?

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 + Swift 2 + Alamofire 3 to upload the images. [My code](https://github.com/enix223/SwiftPlayground/blob/master/SwiftPlayground/TestAlamofireMultiUpload.swift) goes here:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class TestAlamofireMultiUpload: UIViewController {

    var apiUrl: String {
        get {
            return "http://192.168.6.183:8000/api/v1/"  // SD Lib
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let images = [UIImage(named: "test1")!, UIImage(named: "test2")!]
        requestAPIUploadImage("jo21ij3ndooi3okvdani3u43ijfdnk", images: images) { (result) in
            print(result)
        }
    }

    /// Upload file with multipart formdata
    func apiUploadFile(url: String,
                       method: Alamofire.Method,
                       token: String?,
                       multipartFormData: MultipartFormData -> Void,
                       completionHandler: (Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void)) {

        let headers = buildHeaders(token)

        Alamofire.upload(method,
                         "\(apiUrl)\(url)/",
                         headers: headers,
                         multipartFormData: multipartFormData,
                         encodingMemoryThreshold: Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
                         encodingCompletion: {
                            (encodingResult) in
                            switch encodingResult {
                            case .Success(let request, _, _):
                                request
                                    .validate()
                                    .responseJSON(completionHandler: completionHandler)
                            case .Failure(let err):
                                let error = NSError(domain: "test", code: 1, userInfo: ["message": String(err)])
                                let result: Result<AnyObject, NSError> = .Failure(error)
                                let response = Response(request: nil, response: nil, data: nil, result: result)
                                completionHandler(response)
                            }
        })


    }

    /// Upload image
    func requestAPIUploadImage(token: String, images: [UIImage], completion: ((result: Bool) -> Void)) {

        let parameters = ["imageCategory": "1"]

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// How can I make the images upload serially here ????? ///
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        let image = images[0]

        self.apiUploadFile("image/upload", method: .POST, token: token, multipartFormData: {
            (multipartFormData) in

            // import images to multipart
            if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: data, name: "imageFile", fileName: "imageFile.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }

            // import parameters to multipart
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
            }

            }, completionHandler: {
                (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let value):
                    print(value)
                    completion(result: true)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    completion(result: false)
                }
        })
    }

    private func buildHeaders(token: String?) -> [String: String]? {
        var headers = [String: String]()
        if let token = token {
            headers["Authorization"] = "Token \(token)"
        }
        return headers
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `completionHandler:`, in case of success, do the same for next image, etc.

Comment: can you give me an example how to use `completionHandler ` to do it?

Comment: Look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634995/chain-multiple-alamofire-requests

Comment: thanks, it is helpful