# Processing only one request at a time in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire, synchronous

I want to process only one request at a time that on `Alamofire` - meaning when response come for first request it will process the second request and so on.

How to achieve this?

Comment: In success block of first request, make a call for second request and so on

Comment: do you understand objective C code ?

Answer (score 3):

Basically u can select one from the few approaches:

1. Use `NSOperationQueue` - create queue with `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1`, and simply add task in to queue. Sample:

   ```
   let operationQueue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
   operationQueue.name = "name.com"
   operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
   operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock {  
       //do staff here
   }
   ```

   if u need to cancel all task - `operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()`
2. Use `semaphore`

   ```
   dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

   request.execute = {
       //do staff here    
       dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
   }

   dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) //or 
   dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(60 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))) //if u need some timeout
   dispatch_release(semaphore)
   ```
3. `GCD` and `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL`

   ```
   let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("name.com", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

   func test(interval: NSTimeInterval) {
         NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(interval)
         print("\(interval)")
   }
   dispatch_async(serialQueue, {
       test(13)
   })
   dispatch_async(serialQueue, {
       test(1)
    })
   dispatch_async(serialQueue, {
        test(5)
   })
   ```
4. `Mutex` - simple sample [from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) :

> ```
> pthread_mutex_t mutex;
> void MyInitFunction()
> {
>     pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
> }
>
> void MyLockingFunction()
> {
>     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
>     // Do work.
>     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
> }
> ```

5. Use some kind of `NestedChainRequests` - make some class that will handle request one-by-one, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38635938/2012219)
6. Use `PromiseKit` ([link](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)) vs `Alamofire` ([link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire))

The simplest approach I guess is to use `GCD`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dispatch queue or nsoprations and your alamofire task to it. Remember make a synchronous queue

This link might help you
http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/